# Pass percentiles to pandas agg function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, aggregate

I want to pass the numpy `percentile()` function through pandas' `agg()` function as I do below with various other numpy statistics functions.

Right now I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
AGGREGATE   MY_COLUMN
A           10
A           12
B           5
B           9
A           84
B           22
```

And my code looks like this:

```
grouped = dataframe.groupby('AGGREGATE')
column = grouped['MY_COLUMN']
column.agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.std, np.median, np.var, np.min, np.max])
```

The above code works, but I want to do something like

```
column.agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.percentile(50), np.percentile(95)])
```

I.e., specify various percentiles to return from `agg()`.

How should this be done?

Comment: This is probably a newer aspect of Pandas but look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894939/calculate-arbitrary-percentile-on-pandas-groupby. TLDR: df.groupby('C').quantile(.95)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Perhaps not super efficient, but one way would be to create a function yourself:

```
def percentile(n):
    def percentile_(x):
        return x.quantile(n)
    percentile_.__name__ = 'percentile_{:02.0f}'.format(n*100)
    return percentile_
```

Then include this in your `agg`:

```
In [11]: column.agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.std, np.median,
                     np.var, np.min, np.max, percentile(50), percentile(95)])
Out[11]:
           sum       mean        std  median          var  amin  amax  percentile_50  percentile_95
AGGREGATE
A          106  35.333333  42.158431      12  1777.333333    10    84             12           76.8
B           36  12.000000   8.888194       9    79.000000     5    22             12           76.8
```

Note sure this is how it *should* be done though...

Answer (score 78):

You can have `agg()` use a custom function to be executed on specified column:

```
# 50th Percentile
def q50(x):
    return x.quantile(0.5)

# 90th Percentile
def q90(x):
    return x.quantile(0.9)

my_DataFrame.groupby(['AGGREGATE']).agg({'MY_COLUMN': [q50, q90, 'max']})
```

Answer (score 37):

Being more specific, if you just want to aggregate your pandas groupby results using the percentile function, the python lambda function offers a pretty neat solution. Using the question's notation, aggregating by the percentile 95, should be:

```
dataframe.groupby('AGGREGATE').agg(lambda x: np.percentile(x['COL'], q = 95))
```

You can also assign this function to a variable and use it in conjunction with other aggregation functions.

Comment: I'm getting the error TypeError: Must provide 'func' or tuples of '(column, aggfunc). Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Although this looks pretty but def. efficient if you work with big data

Answer (score 33):

I believe the idiomatic way to do this in pandas is:

```
df.groupby("AGGREGATE").quantile([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 1])
```

Answer (score 24):

I really like [the solution Andy Hayden gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17578653/4629950), however, this had multiple issues for me:

- If the dataframe has multiple columns, it aggregated over the columns instead of over the rows?
- For me, the row names were percentile_0.5 (dot instead of underscore). Not sure what caused this, probably that I am using Python 3.
- Need to import numpy as well instead of staying in pandas (I know, numpy is imported implicitely in pandas...)

Here is an updated version that fixes these issues:

```
def percentile(n):
    def percentile_(x):
        return x.quantile(n)
    percentile_.__name__ = 'percentile_{:02.0f}'.format(n*100)
    return percentile_
```

Comment: Do you intend `return x.quantile(n)` in your version?

Comment: Nice catch! I definitely did, thanks for mentioning it. I'll edit it.

Comment: I think the format `{:02.0f}` would be better to avoid spaces for single digit percent values.

Answer (score 20):

Try this for the 50% and 95% percentile:

```
column.describe(percentiles=[0.5, 0.95])
```

Answer (score 14):

For situations where all you need is a subset of the `describe` (typically the most common needed statistics) you can just index the returned pandas series without needing any extra functions.

For example, I commonly find myself just needing to present the 25th, median, 75th and count. This can be done in just one line like so:

```
columns.agg('describe')[['25%', '50%', '75%', 'count']]
```

For specifying your own set of percentiles, the chosen answer is a good choice, but for simple use case, there is no need for extra functions.

Answer (score 12):

```js
df.groupby("AGGREGATE").describe(percentiles=[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 1])
```

by default `describe` function give us `mean, count, std, min, max`, and with percentiles array you can choose the needed percentiles.

Answer (score 12):

More efficient solution with `pandas.Series.quantile` method:

```py
df.groupby("AGGREGATE").agg(("YOUR_COL_NAME", lambda x: x.quantile(0.5))
```

With several percentile values

```py
percentiles = [0.5, 0.9, 0.99]
quantile_funcs = [(p, lambda x: x.quantile(p)) for p in percentiles]
df.groupby("AGGREGATE").agg(quantile_funcs)
```

Comment: I like this, the only problem is the name of the columns

Comment: You can customize the name of the column while defining your aggregate functions: `[(f"percentile_{p}", lambda x: x.quantile(p)) for p in percentiles]`

Comment: TIL. I guess this can also be mixed with other aggregations like `["mean", "std"] + q_fun_list`. Best answer IMHO

Answer (score 6):

Just to throw a more general solution into the ring. Assume you have a DF with just one column to group:

```
df = pd.DataFrame((('A',10),('A',12),('B',5),('B',9),('A',84),('B',22)), 
                    columns=['My_KEY', 'MY_COL1'])
```

One can aggregate and calcualte basically any descriptive metric with a list of anonymous (lambda) functions like:

```
df.groupby(['My_KEY']).agg( [np.sum, np.mean, lambda x: np.percentile(x, q=25)] )
```

However, if you have multiple columns to aggregate, you have to call a non anonymous function or call the columns explicitly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame((('A',10,3),('A',12,4),('B',5,6),('B',9,3),('A',84,2),('B',22,1)), 
                    columns=['My_KEY', 'MY_COL1', 'MY_COL2'])

# non-anonymous function
def percentil25 (x): 
    return np.percentile(x, q=25)

# type 1: call for both columns 
df.groupby(['My_KEY']).agg( [np.sum, np.mean, percentil25 ]  )

# type 2: call each column separately
df.groupby(['My_KEY']).agg( {'MY_COL1': [np.sum, np.mean, lambda x: np.percentile(x, q=25)],
                             'MY_COL2': np.size})
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also perhaps use lambda to achieve the same. Some thing like below piece of code :

```
        agg(
            lambda x: [
                np.min(a=x), 
                np.percentile(q=25,a=x), 
                np.median(a=x), 
                np.percentile(q=75,a=x), 
                np.max(a=x)
    ]
)
```

Comment: how is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: Well, only difference is, you dont need to define a new function. Saves some lines of Code.

Comment: How do you name those function headers? like np.min(a=x) how do you name the header for that function?

Answer (score 4):

This can provide some customization:

```
list_statistics = ['count','mean','min',lambda x: np.percentile(x,q=25),'max',lambda x: np.percentile(x,q=75)]
cols_to_rename = {'<lambda_0>':'P25','<lambda_1>':'P75'}
df_out.groupby('Country').agg(list_statistics).rename(columns=cols_to_rename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple function can be called as below:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import random

C = ['Ram', 'Ram', 'Shyam', 'Shyam', 'Mahima', 'Ram', 'Ram', 'Shyam', 'Shyam', 'Mahima']

A = [ random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10) ]

B = [ random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10) ]

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'field_A': A, 'field_B': B, 'field_C': C })

print(df)

d = df.groupby('field_C')['field_A'].describe()[['mean', 'count', '25%', '50%', '75%']]
print(d)
```

I was unable to call median in this, but able to work other functions.

Comment: this calls all of them, but selects a few. this is bad for performance, which is the reason why you would use `agg` over describe.

Comment: @SebastianWozny may be you can update your comment on which solution do you recommend when dealing with big data

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a dataframe with several columns and only want the quantiles for one column:

```
df.groupby("AGGREGATE")['MY_COLUMN'].quantile([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 1])
```

and in case you want a 1 level dataframe you can add:

```
df.groupby("AGGREGATE")['MY_COLUMN'].quantile([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 1]).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define simple lambda function

```
my_quant = lambda _q: lambda _data:_data.quantile(_q)
```

the use it with the required quantiles

```
df.aggregate([my_quant(0.1),my_quant(0.3),'median',my_quant(0.7)]
```

---

** If you want to keep the aggregations name without renaming the indexes you can create lambda creator and set the function names

```
def lambda_creator(func,name):
    func.__name__ = name
    return func

my_quant = lambda _q: lambda_creator(lambda _data: _data.quantile(_q),f'quantile_{_q}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Q1 result using agg from dataframe groupby, recommend below also.

```
import numpy as np 
df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg(quantile_columns = ('column_name', lambda x: np.percentile(x, q=25)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to group by a column and describe the dataset based on that group. You can use custom lambda functions inside the bracket to create new descriptions for the dataset, and you can add new columns to compare vs. the group.

```
    (df
    .groupby(['AGGREGATE'])
    .agg({
        'MY_COLUMN_1': ['count', 'mean', 'median', 'max', 'min', ('90 pct', lambda x: x.quantile(0.9)), 
        'MY_COLUMN_2': ['count', 'mean', 'median', 'max', 'min', ('90 pct', lambda x: x.quantile(0.9)]
    })).round(1)
```