# How to get more summary of data in pandas

Tags: pandas

Bu using the df.descripton(), I can get description of data with 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% value of the dataframe or series

But if I need to get summary of every 5% of the data, is there any direct way to solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass percentiles to pandas agg function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578115/pass-percentiles-to-pandas-agg-function). I think describe will get a [quantiles argument in 0.14](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4196) which would allow just this!

Answer (score 0):

I found it. it is quantile function in pandas....
I should not be so lazy...
=,=