# Using df.agg(...) on a list of functions fails when a custom function is included in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to aggregate a bunch of columns with two functions each:  `np.mean` and `quart_1`.  All columns are numeric.  `np.mean` is imported from `numpy`, and `quart_1` is a custom function that returns the first quartile of a column:

```
def quart_1(x):
    return np.percentile(x, 25)
```

The issue is that if I do `df.agg([np.mean, quart_1])`, I get `KeyError: no results`.

It appears that the error is that `quart_1` returns the original DataFrame without any aggregation (with some labels) if I include it in a list, but actually performs the aggregation and returns a Pandas series (see below commands and outputs) if I feed it the raw function without a list.

Feeding it `quart_1` as a scalar:

```
df.select_dtypes([np.number]).agg(quart_1)

accelerometer_x     0.445186
accelerometer_y    10.619320
dtype: float64
```

...and inside of a list:

```
df.select_dtypes([np.number]).agg([quart_1])

                            accelerometer_x accelerometer_y
                                quart_1         quart_1
gps_time                                               
2017-07-27 18:35:14.660        0.519700       10.703300
2017-07-27 18:35:14.665        0.474200       10.684200
2017-07-27 18:35:14.670        0.474200       10.684200
2017-07-27 18:35:14.675        0.574800       10.633900
2017-07-27 18:35:14.680        0.574800       10.633900
2017-07-27 18:35:14.685        0.528103       10.657099
2017-07-27 18:35:14.690        0.476600       10.681800
2017-07-27 18:35:14.695        0.446749       10.694255
2017-07-27 18:35:14.700        0.476600       10.681800
2017-07-27 18:35:14.705        0.574800       10.643500
2017-07-27 18:35:14.710        0.574800       10.643500
```

Comment: DataFrame.agg is relatively new so I guess this is a bug. Earlier, we were using this hack when there were no df.agg: `df.groupby(np.ones(len(df))).agg([np.mean, quart_1])`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that for some reason, when passed within a list, the dimension of the input vector changes.  Replacing `x` with `x.T` within `quart_1` did the trick.  I have additional percentiles not mentioned here, and it seems like using `quart_1` and `quart_3` (same as `quart_1`, but with 25 replaced with 75) led to some kind of a name clash.  I fixed it by using a `percentile` function as mentioned [in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578115/pass-percentiles-to-pandas-agg-function)