# Pandas groupby quantile values

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to calculate specific quantile values from a data frame, as shown in the code below. There was no problem when calculate it in separate lines.

When attempting to run last 2 lines, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'quantile(0.25)'
```

How can I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        'y': [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
        'number': [25000, 35000, 45000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 65000, 36000]
    }
)
f = {'number': ['median', 'std', 'quantile']}
df1 = df.groupby('x').agg(f)
df.groupby('x').quantile(0.25)
df.groupby('x').quantile(0.75)

# code below with problem:
f = {'number': ['median', 'std', 'quantile(0.25)', 'quantile(0.75)']}
df1 = df.groupby('x').agg(f)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17578653/4686625

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I prefer def functions

```
def q1(x):
    return x.quantile(0.25)

def q3(x):
    return x.quantile(0.75)

f = {'number': ['median', 'std', q1, q3]}
df1 = df.groupby('x').agg(f)
df1
Out[1643]: 
  number                            
  median           std     q1     q3
x                                   
0  52500  17969.882211  40000  61250
1  43000  16337.584481  35750  55000
```

Comment: I tried lambda didn't work thought of function you posted already

Comment: Nope since lambda will return a column name lambda it would lead to specification error. Wonder how you would make it

Comment: @Dark something like fl = lambda x : x.quantile(0.25)
fl.__name__ = 'f1'

Comment: I meant with this one `f = {'number': ['median', 'std', lambda x: x.quantile(0.25), lambda x: x.quantile(0.75)]}` , certainly didn't thinkg of assigning to a variable.

Comment: @Dark this one can not , return the duplicated lambda name :-) , you are right

Comment: Just a note: Q2 is the median, not the 75th percentile. Your second function should be named `q3`

Answer (score 20):

[@WeNYoBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/wenyoben)'s answer is great. There is one limitation though, and that lies with the fact that one needs to create a new function for every quantile. This can be a very unpythonic exercise if the number of quantiles become large. A better approach is to use a function to create a function, and to rename that function appropriately.

```
def rename(newname):
    def decorator(f):
        f.__name__ = newname
        return f
    return decorator

def q_at(y):
    @rename(f'q{y:0.2f}')
    def q(x):
        return x.quantile(y)
    return q

f = {'number': ['median', 'std', q_at(0.25) ,q_at(0.75)]}
df1 = df.groupby('x').agg(f)
df1

Out[]:
number                            
  median           std  q0.25  q0.75
x                                   
0  52500  17969.882211  40000  61250
1  43000  16337.584481  35750  55000
```

The rename decorator renames the function so that the pandas agg function can deal with the reuse of the quantile function returned (otherwise all quantiles results end up in columns that are named q).

Comment: Nice! No need for the decorator, though: you can just rename `q` before returning it from `q_at`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice way if you want to give names to aggregated columns:

```
df1.groupby('x').agg(
    q1_foo=pd.NamedAgg('number', q1),
    q2_foo=pd.NamedAgg('number', q2)
)
```

where `q1` and `q2` are functions.

Or even simpler:

```
df1.groupby('x').agg(
    q1_foo=('number', q1),
    q2_foo=('number', q2)
)
```