# Pandas: Groupby two columns and find 25th, median, 75th percentile AND mean of 3 columns in LONG format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is an example DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 10, 11, 12],
                    [1, 1, 13, 14, 15], 
                    [1, 2, 16, 17, 18], 
                    [1, 2, 19, 20, 21],
                    [1, 3, 22, 23, 24], 
                    [1, 3, 25, 26, 27],
                    [1, 4, 28, 29, 30], 
                    [1, 4, 31, 32, 33], 
                    [1, 4, 34, 35, 36],
                    [1, 4, 37, 38, 39],
                    [1, 4, 40, 41, 42]])

df.columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3']
print(df)
```

Gives:

```
    c1  c2  p1  p2  p3
0    1   1  10  11  12
1    1   1  13  14  15
2    1   2  16  17  18
3    1   2  19  20  21
4    1   3  22  23  24
5    1   3  25  26  27
6    1   4  28  29  30
7    1   4  31  32  33
8    1   4  34  35  36
9    1   4  37  38  39
10   1   4  40  41  42
```

What I have done so far:

```
example = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2'])['p1', 'p2', 'p3'].quantile([0.25, 0.50, 0.75]).unstack().reset_index()

print(example)
```

Gives:

```
  c1 c2     p1                  p2                  p3             
          0.25   0.5   0.75   0.25   0.5   0.75   0.25   0.5   0.75
0  1  1  10.75  11.5  12.25  11.75  12.5  13.25  12.75  13.5  14.25
1  1  2  16.75  17.5  18.25  17.75  18.5  19.25  18.75  19.5  20.25
2  1  3  22.75  23.5  24.25  23.75  24.5  25.25  24.75  25.5  26.25
3  1  4  31.00  34.0  37.00  32.00  35.0  38.00  33.00  36.0  39.00
```

The output I have above is CORRECT to find the percentiles, but I also want the `Average/Mean` + The above format is in `wide` format, **I would like it to be in `long` format.**

So,

In the `wide` format, I would want another column called `average`

```
  c1 c2     p1                          p2                              p3             
          0.25   0.5   0.75  average    0.25   0.5   0.75   average     0.25   0.5   0.75   average
0  1  1  10.75  11.5  12.25     X       11.75  12.5  13.25     X        12.75  13.5  14.25    X
1  1  2  16.75  17.5  18.25     X       17.75  18.5  19.25     X        18.75  19.5  20.25    X
2  1  3  22.75  23.5  24.25     X       23.75  24.5  25.25     X        24.75  25.5  26.25    X
3  1  4  31.00  34.0  37.00     X       32.00  35.0  38.00     X        33.00  36.0  39.00    X
```

The final OUTPUT that I'm looking for is the above table in `long` format like so:

```
    c1      c2      0.25    0.50    0.75    average      p
    1       1       10.75   11.5    12.25      X         1
    1       1       11.75   12.5    13.25      X         2
    1       1       2.75    13.5    14.25      X         3
    1       2       16.75   17.5    18.25      X         1
    1       2       17.75   18.5    19.25      X         2
    1       2       18.75   19.5    20.25      X         3
```

I'm having two troubles.. I don't know how and where to include the portion that calculates the `mean` ALONG with the `25th, 50th and 75th percentile`, and converting it to a `long` format..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

```
df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).describe().stack(level=0)[['25%', '50%', '75%', 'mean']]
```

Comment: Nice answer!  I didn't know you could just pass in quantile values with `describe()`.

Answer (score 5):

Define wrapper functions for `quantile`, then pass in a list of calculations (including `mean`):

```
def q1(x):
    return x.quantile(0.25)

def q2(x):
    return x.median()

def q3(x):
    return x.quantile(0.75)

df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).agg(['mean', q1, q2, q3]).stack(level=0)

          mean     q1    q2     q3
c1 c2                             
1  1  p1  11.5  10.75  11.5  12.25
      p2  12.5  11.75  12.5  13.25
      p3  13.5  12.75  13.5  14.25
   2  p1  17.5  16.75  17.5  18.25
      p2  18.5  17.75  18.5  19.25
      p3  19.5  18.75  19.5  20.25
   3  p1  23.5  22.75  23.5  24.25
      p2  24.5  23.75  24.5  25.25
      p3  25.5  24.75  25.5  26.25
   4  p1  34.0  31.00  34.0  37.00
      p2  35.0  32.00  35.0  38.00
      p3  36.0  33.00  36.0  39.00
```

To get your exact desired output (no MultiIndex and column renamed to `p`), add this to the end of the method chain:

```
.reset_index().rename(columns={"level_2":"p"})
```

Note: This answer is largely inspired by [Wen's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637774/pandas-groupby-quantile-values).